# Decoding control characters inside a string in Java is different compared to what was encoded

Tags: java, hex

I am receiving a string array from the database which has control characters as delimiters.

The delimiters used are (in hex) 01, 02, 03, 04, and 05. When decoding the same on my end in Java, 01, 02 and 03 decode as is no matter which encoding I use, however

04 is decoded as **156** (toCharArray native on mac) and **3F** (ASCII) which is **'?'**

05 is decoded as **09** (toCharArray native on mac and ASCII) which is **'\t'**

```
    String test4 = "t035t735    ";
    for(char d: test4.toCharArray())
    {
         int x = d;
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    byte[] bytes = test4.getBytes("US-ASCII");


    for(byte b : bytes)
    {
        System.out.print(b + " ");
    }
```

What I get back is

116 48 3 51 53 156 116 55 3 51 53 **156 9**

116 48 3 51 53 63 116 55 3 51 53 **63 9**

For the same two chars the output when queried in the database(in hex)

.   .

0  0

4  5

Any inputs on what might be happening here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: The only answer anyone has enough information to say is "because your code's wrong".

Comment: There is no hex encoding/decoding here. What you're doing is converting between bytes and characters.

Comment: If you have the data in a Java string then the encoding is Unicode/UTF-16 code units. So, the problem could be how you get the data into the string. Perhaps you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: "hexadecimal character" isn't correct - these would be '0', '1',... '9', 'A',... 'F', as they are used to denote hexadecimal numbers. What you should have said is: "control characters".)

These are the true character codes you have in that string (according to your first output line) from the DB (*not* the one you are showing):

```
116 48 3         51 53 156       116 55 3       51  53 156    9
t   0  \u0003    3  5  \u009c    t   7  \u0003  3   5  \u009c \u0009
```

\u0003 is control character ETX (end of text).

\u009c is the (non-printable) control character called String Terminator

\u0009 is indeed the control character TAB (tabulate)

If you try to decode this using US-ASCII,

```
116 48 3 51 53 63 116 55 3 51 53 63 9
            ?                 ?
```

the String Terminator is converted to '?', which is perfectly clear, since US-ASCII ends with character \u007F = 127, and everything beyond this upper limit is (by definition) converted to '?'.

So I guess you should split on characters \u0003 and \u009c and \u0009 (and some more?) to get the chunks of data in between.

```
String test4 = "t0\u000335\u009ct7\u000335\u0009";
for(char d: test4.toCharArray()) {
    int x = d;
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}
System.out.println();
String[] chunks = test4.split( "[\u0001-\u0005\u0009\u009c]" );
String del = "";
for( String s: chunks ){
    System.out.print( del + "\""  +s + "\"" );
    del = ", ";
}
System.out.println();
```

Output:

```
116 48 3 51 53 156 116 55 3 51 53 9 
"t0", "35", "t7", "35"
```

Comment: Yes, they are indeed "control characters", my bad. Thanks for the detailed explanation. However it does not solve what I am trying to understand. On the other end this is what is being built..  String test4 = "t0\u000335\u009ct7\u000335\u0009";

Comment: And I get back  116 48 3 51 53 156 116 55 3 51 53 156 9

Comment: There is another \u009c (=156) right before the final TAB - but I have explained just that. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: I have, of course, no idea what to expect - the data between the delimiters. Perhaps \u009c and/or \u0009 is part of the data?

Comment: Tom's comment is interesting: How *are* you receiving the data from the DB? As a byte array? Can you print the original byte values?